# i want to apply condition on foreach

Tags: php, html, json

i want to apply condition on json array using php here to display only data that has type discursive

[my json file](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0bd18448a632508b2534de51e09649c8%5C)

here is the code to i am trying but it is not showing the data i want to

```
 <?php
  $obj2 = json_decode($blog_data);
  foreach(array_reverse($obj2->blogs) as $blog)
  {
    if($obj2>b_type == 'discursive')
  {
  ?>
      <h3> <?php echo $blog->name; ?></h3>
      <span> <?php echo $blog->date; ?> </span>
        <p><?php echo $blog->b_text; ?></p>
   <?php
  }
  else{
    echo "no discursive event";
  }
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `foreach` loop you should access current "blog" item (i.e. `$blog`), but not common object `$obj2`:

```
...
foreach(array_reverse($obj2->blogs) as $blog)
{
    if ($blog->b_type == 'discursive')
...
```

Comment: @HaroonAslam because it supposed to find the answer just by searching on google though or maybe some people express their negativity through a 'button power' .Anyway don't worry ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <?php
    $obj2 = json_decode($blog_data);
    foreach(array_reverse($obj2->blogs) as $blog)
    {
        if($blog->b_type == 'discursive')
        {
       ?>
            <h3> <?php echo $blog->name; ?></h3>
            <span> <?php echo $blog->date; ?> </span>
            <p><?php echo $blog->b_text; ?></p>
        <?php
       }
        else{
            echo "no discursive event";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the variable `$blog` inside the if condition and not `$obj2`.

```
<?php
$obj2 = json_decode($blog_data);
foreach (array_reverse($obj2->blogs) as $blog) {
    if ($blog > b_type === 'discursive') {
?>
          <h3> <?php
        echo $blog->name;
?></h3>
          <span> <?php
        echo $blog->date;
?> </span>
            <p><?php
        echo $blog->b_text;
?></p>
       <?php
    } else {
        echo "no discursive event";
    }
}
?>
```

Also:

- Always compare using strict comparison using `===` and not `==`. Have a look at [this article](https://www.copterlabs.com/strict-vs-loose-comparisons-in-php/) for reasons why you should do this.